# How to remove home-screens on a Vodafone 845?

Tags: home-screen

Good day,

after playing around with the Vodafone 845 (Android 2.1) icons positions I ended up with additional empty home-screens (or are they desktops, not sure for the term). What is the proper way to remove those empty screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with the default launcher. However, with a lot of home screen replacements you can define how many home screens to have. (Zeam, Go Launcher, and Launcher Pro do, for sure.)

Comment: Loks like this phone comes with a funny custom homescreen app: "Android 2.1 comes with five home screens that you can flick through from side to side. With the 845, if you drag an icon to the border of the existing home screens, a new home screen is created. In effect, you can create an unlimited number of rows and columns to fit all the icons and widgets you want." - http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/smartphones/279154/vodafone-845

Comment: yes, it seems there's no obvious way to remove newly created screens with the default launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Nicked from [here](http://androidforums.com/captivate-support-troubleshooting/247287-delete-unwanted-home-screens.html):

> Menu -> Edit. Click the red (-) button in the upper-right corner of the screens you want to delete. Use the [+] button at the bottom to add a new screen.

Comment: Perhaps with the Captivate, but the stock Android launcher doesn't have any such options.

Comment: @Al correct, but the article I linked to in the comment on your answer says this phone has a custom home screen, so I don't think it is the stock home screen we're talking about here

Comment: @Foley: I wish these carriers would stop overcustomizing this stuff.

Comment: @Foley: whether we call it custom or default(stock) launcher - I didn't find the way to remove those screens. I gave LauncherPro a try but first impression was not so good (the touchpad didn't work for screen scrolling). Perhaps I will stick with the default launcher meanwhile.

Comment: @dindras Odd, the stock launcher also doesn't automatically create new home screens...

Comment: I found this option in both Eclair (2.1. 2.1-update1) as well as Froyo (2.2) - on Samsung Galaxy S. In fact in froyo, the red X button has been dumped for drag-and-drop (to trash) style removal of home screens.