# Removing desktop panes on Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10, 3.1-honeycomb

I have a brand new Galaxy Tab 10.1 and I can't figure out how I remove some of the desktop panes.

Comment: Do you mean home screens? If so, see this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4594/how-to-remove-home-screens-on-a-vodafone-845 . There's also this one, which is about HTC Sense, but some of the solutions may help: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4676/how-to-reduce-number-of-screens-on-htc-sense-android-phones

Answer (score 1):

To remove some of the desktop panes, you will have to use an alternative launcher. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Honeycomb so I can't give you any recommendations besides looking in the Play Store.